# Why AJAX call is not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making an AJAX call to an API like this,

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=APLE",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){
        var status = results.response.Status;
        var company = results.response.Symbol;
        $('#results').append(status + '. Company is: ' + company);
       }
 });
</script>
```

Once I receive the response, I am trying to parse certain data from it and append it to a `<div>` in the `<body>`.

```
<body>

  <div id="results"></div>

</body>
```

I have the code that I am working on here - http://jsbin.com/hofosaveho/edit?html,output

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your returned object doesn't have a response property

try:

```
  success: function(results){
        alert(results);
        var status = results.Status;
        var company = results.Name;
        $('#results').append(status + ' OK. Company is: ' + company);
    }
```

[see demo](http://jsbin.com/xoperufuko/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 2):

this is your sample response

```
[object Object] {
  Change: 0.0999999999999979,
  ChangePercent: 0.507356671740223,
  ChangePercentYTD: -0.801201802704057,
  ChangeYTD: 19.97,
  High: 19.81,
  LastPrice: 19.81,
  Low: 19.57,
  MarketCap: 3460113650,
  MSDate: 42460.6659722222,
  Name: "",
  Open: 19.76,
  Status: "SUCCESS",
  Symbol: "APLE",
  Timestamp: "Thu Mar 31 15:59:00 UTC-04:00 2016",
  Volume: 49025
}
```

perhaps update your server return ?